# Jupyter Notebook showing extra kernels? How to remove them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a single conda environment: py9 (along with the base Python3 env). I'm not sure what happened, but now Jupyter is showing the following kernels:

[image]

Why is Jupyter showing those two extra kernels? Is there a way to remove them?

```
(base) C:\Users\admin>jupyter kernelspec list
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `ListKernelSpecs`.
Available kernels:
  py9        C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\py9
  python3    C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```